# How can I translate transaction E-Mails

Tags: email

How can I translate my transaction E-Mails.
At my Template, I have this

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

And on my german shop the 'Sku' should be 'Artikelnummer' or 'Object' -> 'Artikel'
I tried to add the words in my translate.csv like this

```
"Mage_Sales:Item","Artikel"
"Mage_Sales:Sku","Artikelnr."
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this (double '::' between the module and the text):

```
"Mage_Sales::Item","Artikel"
"Mage_Sales::Sku","Artikelnr."
```

Also you can place this inside `Mage_Sales.csv`

```
"Item","Artikel"
"Sku","Artikelnr."
```

Comment: I want to change it in my own theme, because of magento core updates. all of my translations are in "app/design/frontend/mytheme/locale/translate.csv"

Comment: The Magento core does not include the `de_DE` locale folder, so you can safely modify any files in there.

Comment: Ok, I made the Translation at app/locale/de_DE/Mage_Sales.csv.  Thank you, I'll test it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the translations in `app/locale/de_DE/Mage_Sales.csv`?

Comment: No I have ONE file in app/design/frontend/mytheme/locale/translate.csv
There are all of my own translations, like
"Mage_Customer::Login or Create an Account", "Anmeldung"
"Mage_Customer::New Customers", "Nein"
"Mage_Customer::Registered Customers", "Ja"

Answer (score -1):

I run across a similar problem when trying to send localized transactional emails from within a cronjob - the localization stuff wasn't initialized. For me calling `Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);` before sendTransactional() helped.